# Using Curl to retrieve json data in php

Tags: json, curl

Am trying to use curl to retrieve json data. if I echo the result as in the case below

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
```

The json result will look like below

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 100
                    [food] => Rice
                    [created] => 2017-07-05T04:02:58.429Z
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 112
                    [food] => Beans
                    [created] => 2017-07-05T03:58:46.269Z
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 115
                    [food] => Potato
                    [created] => 2017-07-05T03:57:50.038Z
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 120
                    [food] => Yam
                    [created] => 2017-07-05T03:55:21.559Z
                )


        )

)
```

Below is the code i used to print the json result

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "myapi.com", 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
//CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"accept: application/json", 
"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
), 
));

$result = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


$json = json_decode($result, true);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';

foreach ($json as  $value) {
echo $value['items']['id'];
echo $value['items']['food'];

}
```

Now am trying to get values for Id and food items only by using the code below but its not displaying anything

```
foreach ($json as  $value) {
    echo $value['items']['id'];
    echo $value['items']['food'];

    }
```

can any one help me fix that by getting the values for items id and food. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just got your foreach loop a bit off. $json is an array, with a single property called `items` - that property is another array, and its THIS array that you actually want to foreach, with arrays that contain your ids and foods n whatnot

```
foreach ($json['items'] as  $value) {echo $value['id'];echo $value['food'];}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got your object hierarchy off a bit. `$value['items']` is an array so you would need to have something like `$value['items'][0]['id']` etc.

Comment: its not displaying anything with your example above

Comment: I misread the output from print_r... I think you want `$value[0]['id']` I would do a print_r on $value to make sure it's the structure you think it is and build up from there.